# Assign a typedef arraytype in a template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a templated class like this example:

```
template<class T>
struct Storage {
    void Push(const T& src) {
        store[i++] = src;  //Is not possible, when T is Tuppel Type
    }
    T store[10];
    int i = 0;
};

Storage<int> ok;
typedef int Tuppel[2];
Storage<Tuppel> nok;

void test() {
    int a = 42;
    Tuppel b = { 1,2 };
    ok.Push(a);
    nok.Push(b);    //Will fail
}
```

How can I make this template valid? Template parameter `T` should be one of:

- Primitive type
- Object Type (`store[i++] = src` should call the assignment operator)
- Arraytypes like `Tuppel` in the example (`store[i++] = src` should call the assignment operator for each array element)

Answer (score 0):

You can either specialise `Storage` for array types, and/or use `std::array` instead of `[]` arrays.

```
#include <array>

Storage<std::array<int, 2>> also_ok;

template<class T, size_t N>
struct Storage<T[N]> {
    void Push(const T (&src)[N]) {
        std::copy_n(src, N, store[i++]);
    }
    T store[10][N];
    int i = 0;
};

Storage<int[2]> now_ok;
```